# How to assign kubernetes master components to a specific node pool?

Tags: kubernetes

For my own deployments I can use [node selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector) to make them run on a specific node pool. I want to do the same thing for [kubernetes master pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/).

(Motivation: I upgraded the kubernetes cluster today causing the aforementioned pods to be moved to some random node pool which I want to prevent from happening again in the future.)

Comment: Hi, Which k8s components pods you want to deploy on specifics node pools? As I understand certain components need to be on each node. for example, kubelet, kube-proxy.

Comment: I want all those components on a specific node pool that don't need to run on every node.

Comment: Kubelet, Kube-Proxy needs to be up and running on each worker node. Because of these components cluster is up and running. If these components are not on the nodes then the status of the node would be `NotReady`.  I am not sure which other components are you referring to ?

Comment: You misread my comment. I'm don't care about these node specific components. I care in k8s terms about "Master Components".